# How does a medic unit heal someone in Starcraft?

Tags: video-games, starcraft

As in the title, how does the medic unit heal soldiers by simply beaming at them and what is the (pseudo-)scientific explanation?

Comment: Questions of real-life science are off-topic.

Comment: @valorum if your edit didnt change the question itself too much it more sounds like a question if what you see ther eon screen is an abbreviation or if ther is really a healing via "beam" in that universe and if so what that beam is there (nanites,...).     if the original formulation was the same then I would interpret the question that way and not about real life science.

Comment: @Thomas - The way it was formulated originally was "is it possible in real life" which isn't acceptable.

Comment: @valorum ah ok then I say +1 to your comment (thought already that you meant pre edit question there with that comment but was not sure as I didnt see the question pre edit)

Comment: "Turn your head and cough."

Comment: Obligatory follow up question: how do priests/monks heal by chanting hoyohoyo?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is addressed in the game's tie-in [Field Manual](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft_Field_Manual). What you've described as a

> "beam"

in fact contains '*attenuating lasers*' (presumably to cauterise wounds) as well as acting as a transport for '*nano-conveyed anesthetics*', '*chemical modifiers*' and nanobots capable of '*cellular hyper-repair*'.

[image]

Comment: You can read the full manual [here](http://imgur.com/gallery/9Zqy9).

Comment: yeah in the game medics really just feel like they pump up the marines full of pain killers till they die anyway a short time later

Comment: @Himarm well the marines _do_ have "stimulant" packs which reduce their lifetime. I always envisioned them basically taking massive drugs..

Comment: @enderland that's literally how it works. They're all expendable, drugged up criminals.

Comment: I have actually had surgery that involved a staple gun. It isn't pleasant but it is effective!

Comment: @Himarm then doesn't that make medic unit are sadist and marine M.